# re2 regex to match emails not delivered by gapps mailing list

Tags: regex, google-apps

I have been trying for some time to write a regex to match those emails not delivered by a Google Apps mailing list.

I have some message modification going on in the sending routing on our domain which adds an additional recipient to all outgoing email - a mailing list `management@domain.co.uk`.
The issue is that the mailing list also gets added on during the delivery to said mailing list, creating message loops that end in messages being bounced.

Looking at the message logs, I can see that the mailing list delivery comes from sender `management+bncBAABBB6J6WGAKGQEEL6JVVI@domain.co.uk` (where `BAABBB6J6WGAKGQEEL6JVVI` is random every time).

I'm after a regex that will match emails that do not come from this mailing list so that the additional recipient is only added to emails sent by users. The only options in the settings for the sending routing are 'Execute this setting only if the envelope sender matches:' and then a field for a regexp. So what I want in there is a regexp that matches for anything that is not `management+bnc.....@domain.co.uk`.

GApps uses re2 regular expression syntax. So far I have `((management\+bnc)(.*?))(@domain\.co\.uk)` which successfully matches `management+bncBAABBB6J6WGAKGQEEL6JVVI@domain.co.uk` but I am unable to work out how to negate the `management+bncBAABBB6J6WGAKGQEEL6JVVI` portion to match only those emails not from this mailing list.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is too simple for what you're doing, but if you can isolate this string, it always begins with "management+bnc", and the random bits are always the same length (23 digits in this case), you can just pull out the substring...

```
string substring = yourstring.Substring(14, 23);
string newEmail = yourstring.Replace(substring, "");
```

Comment: Unfortunately, all I have is one field which accepts a regex. If it matches, the routing gets applied, if not, it doesn't.